# global variables in python / discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So I have declared 3 variables in the very beggining of the code

```
setup_prefix = None
setup_role: Role = None
setup_channel: TextChannel = None
```

Then with the `on_message`event I tried to call them and alter their values

```
async def on_message(message):
    if servers_setup[message.guild.id]['Step1']:
        global setup_prefix
        setup_prefix = message.content
        servers_setup[message.guild.id]['Step1'] = False
        await message.channel.send("Now, mention the role you want to have admin rights")
        servers_setup[message.guild.id]['Step2'] = True
    if servers_setup[message.guild.id]['Step2']:
        global setup_role
        setup_role: Role = message.content
        servers_setup[message.guild.id]['Step2'] = False
        await message.channel.send("Now, mention the channel where do you want the logs to go into")
        servers_setup[message.guild.id]['Step3'] = True
    if servers_setup[message.guild.id]['Step3']:
        global setup_channel
        setup_channel: TextChannel = message.content
        servers_setup[message.guild.id]['Step3'] = False
        await message.channel.send("Great, now I can take care of the rest!")
        changeprefix(message, setup_prefix)
        changeadmin(message, setup_role)
        changelogs(message, setup_channel)
        await message.channel.send("Everything was configured. Have a nice day")
```

The first one (`setup_prefix`) goes without any problem BUT the second one however throws me an error in console when I fire up the bot

```
SyntaxError: annotated name 'role_setup' can't be global
```

I don't know where the problem is...

Comment: Error message says `'role_setup'`, but actual is `'setup_role'`. That doesn't seem correct. Are you having the same code that you executed?

Comment: Seems like a bug in python: https://bugs.python.org/issue34939 Updating to a newer version of python should help

Comment: @Axiumin_ - That's a different situation where the variable annotation was placed after the function with the `global` keyword. This is a case of the annotation of a global variable in the function itself. Suppose different functions annotated differently, what is a linter to do?

Comment: @Austin It Is the same code. I tried to change the name of the variable just to be sure there wasn't a problem with its name. Then it didn't work and I undid the changes in the code. I didn't run the code again so the names are different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be simplified to

```
def foo():
    global bar
    bar:int = 1
```

When run you get

```
  File "test.py", line 3
    bar:int = 1
    ^
SyntaxError: annotated name 'bar' can't be global
```

From PEP 526 - Syntax for Variable Annotations, [When annotations aren't allowed](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#id11):

> It is illegal to attempt to annotate variables subject to global or
> nonlocal in the same function scope... The reason is that global and
> nonlocal don't own variables; therefore, the type annotations belong
> in the scope owning the variable.

You annotated in the scope of the variable at the top of the script. No need to try it again in the function. Just change that bit of code to

```
if servers_setup[message.guild.id]['Step2']:
    global setup_role
    setup_role = message.content
```

Comment: Ok thanks, next time I'm on my computer I'll fix it. If it works I'll mark this as the answer